# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un array como parámetro en un objeto instanciado?

Tags: java

me preguntaba como puedo pasar una variable de tipo array como parámetro dentro de un objeto instanciado mostrando los objetos que contiene la lista

Las demás variables ya están definidas antes en el código.

Y después de crear la variable va la lista de elementos.

Eso no entiendo, como puedo meter un array dentro del objeto instanciado.

¿Cómo hago?

¿Meto el objeto dentro de un bucle for?

Este es el ejemplo:

```
String[] listaArticulos;

listaArticulso = {"Elemento 1", "Elemento 2", "Elemento 3"};

Clase objeto1 = new Clase(numeroRevista, tituloRevista, listaArticulos[]);

System.out.print(objeto1);
```

Si me pueden ayudar lo agradezco.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es del todo clara. Puedes pasar el parámetro en el constructor, o puedes crear un método (se llaman métodos *setter*) para pasar el array al objeto ya instanciado. En el código que muestras no nos dices exactamente cuál es el problema, pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: ya intentaste usando varargs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es pasarle el array al instanciar el objeto, lo que te ocurre es un error de sintaxis. Al pasarle el array como parametro no debes poner "[]". Por lo que te quedaria algo como esto:

```
Clase objeto1 = new Clase(numeroRevista, tituloRevista, listaArticulos);
```

Si esto no te funciona, nos seria de mucha ayuda que compartieses el constructor de tu clase "Clase" para ver que es lo que espera tu clase como parametros.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que intentas preguntar es cómo pasar al parámetro de un constructor un array completo. Lo podrías hacer de la siguiente manera:
Se debe añadir como parámetro una lista, así no se debe controlar la longitud del array y obtendrá un array de cualquier longitud.

Constructor de la clase de la cual se instancia el objeto:

```
//Atributo:
int numeroRevista;
String tituloRevista;
String[] listaArticulos;
//Constructor:
public Clase(int numeroRevista, String tituloRevista,String... listaArticulos){
this.numeroRevista=numeroRevista;
this.tituloRevista=tituloRevista;
this.listaArticulos=listaArticulos;
}
```

Y al pasar los parámetros al objeto instanciado sería así:

```
//Pasar los parámetros en la clase que tiene main.
String[] listaArticulos;
listaArticulso = {"Elemento 1", "Elemento 2", "Elemento 3"};
Clase objeto1 = new Clase(int numeroRevista,String tituloRevista, listaArticulos);
//Para que funcione bien el toString deberías sobreescribirlo, lo pongo sobreescrito más adelante.
System.out.print(objeto1.toString());
```

```
//toString() de la clase.
public String toString(){
return String.format("\n%s: \n%s: %d \n%s: %s \n%s: \n%s","Datos de la revista","Número de la revista",numeroRevista,"Título de la revista",tituloRevista,"Artículos",listaArticulos.toString());
}
```

Comment: Cuando llamas a una función incluido el constructor que es una función especial, no se escribe el tipo de dato en los parámetros.

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo de enviar parámetros a un método o constructor:

```
 //variables a enviar
 String dato1="Dato";
 String[] datosArr={"Elemento 1", "Elemento 2", "Elemento 3"};
 List<String> list=new ArrayList();
 list.add("Dato1");
 list.add("Dato2");
 //llamada al metodo           
 recibeDatos(dato1, datosArr, list);

 public void recibeDatos(String dato1, String[] datosArr, List<String> list){ //aqui el procedimiento}
```

Comment: ¿Como se aplicaría para resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta?. revisar [answer],saludos.

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer de varias maneras te enseñare 2 de las que en lo particular yo uso

La primera forma sería establecer el parametro y javascript intuye que tipo de dato es (en este caso un arreglo)..

```
let arreglo1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
//Clase generada o funcion

function procesararreglo1(parametroArreglo){ // Esto es en una función
  console.log(parametroArreglo)
}

procesararreglo1(arreglo1); // le pasas el parametro y la función imprimira el valor
```

o si lo necesita en una clase tienes algo asi

```
let arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
class miClase{
  constructor(arregloparametro){
      console.log(arregloparametro);
  }
}
```

.............

Esta es la SEGUNDA forma que me gusta

tenemos la misma función y clase ..

```
function funcionEspecial(...parametroarreglo){//Este operador ... indica que recibira un parametro y sabrá que es un arreglo
 console.log(parametroarreglo);
}
```

la forma de invocarlo es la siguiente

```
functionEspecial(1,2,3,4,"santiago","betweencode")// nosotros mandamos muchos parametros pero cuando lo reciba la función lo "transformara en arreglo"
```

para la clase es lo mismo

```
class claseEspecial{
 constructor(...arregloparametro){
  console.log(arregloparametro);
}
}


new claseEspecial(1,2,3,4,"cualquier cosa","final"); //Asi lo invocaria
```

Saludos :D

Comment: Si la version de java es menor a la 9 seria usando nashorn para correr js, si es menor a  bison, pero para versiones posteriores como sigieres correr js si se descontinuaron los scriptEngine?